# OS X Hello World Swift tutorial

Tags: swift, macos

So I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/731-macos-development-for-beginners-part-1) for Swift and am not getting the desired result at the end. This is my code for the `ViewController`:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var helloLabel: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sayButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        var name = nameField.stringValue
        if name.isEmpty {
            name = "World"
        }
        let greeting = "Hello \(name)!"
        helloLabel.stringValue = greeting
    }

}
```

And the following is the result:

[image]

When I debug the program however it does show the correct variables:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but how big is the label? Is "World!" getting cut off maybe?

Comment: "When I debug the program however it does show the correct variables” ... Hmm. The “Variables View" down in the “Debug area”, seems to be showing your variables correctly. Or are you saying that the `helloLabel` doesn’t appear to be showing the full `greeting`?

Comment: `You can’t tell how long a name a user might enter, so resize the field to fit the height of that font and to almost fill the width of the window.`  Did you miss this step from the tutorial?

Comment: Note, your breakpoint is still in the `sayButtonClicked`, right before you executed the `helloLabel.stringValue = ...` line. When single stepping through your code, you won’t see the change reflected in the UI. You have to press "continue execution” button before you’ll see the change reflected in the view...

Comment: Can you show your variables when you're stopped on line 32?

Comment: It was the label, very silly of me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I didn't stretch out the the Label field enough.

Comment: Well done, providing an answer that solves the problem. (voted)